Incorrect click coordinates for events caused by react onClick handler
I'm seeing weird behavior with react onClick handlers when device emulation mode is turned on in Chrome (and also in my own capacitorjs apps running on an Android device).
Essentially, clicks right around an element with an onClick handler seem to push the click event's clientX and clientY coordinates back inside the element's bounds.  I've created a codesandbox to show the issue.
If you remove the onClick handler or are not in device emulation mode, the effect goes away.
Specifically in my app, I have a full-height clickable item in my app's header, and another clickable element directly below the header, but when clicking within ~10px of the header, the header's onClick handler fires instead of the element I actually clicked on.
Edit: For my specific use-case, the issue seemed to be that one of my elements was using react's built-in onClick handlers, and the other was using a home-rolled <Touch> component that used onTouch* handlers (to support things like long-pressing), as I was not able to recreate my issue using two onClick handling elements right next to one another.
